# How Do I Cache Just the Homepage with Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cache

This config is close...

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

...but it does all php pages, not just the home page like I want.

Basically the developer said he wants example.com to be cached, while:

http://example.com/electronics/

would not be cached.

Note the developer is using pretty URLs with an MVC framework that runs everything through index.php.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache FilesMatch directive accepts regular expressions, but that should also mean you can fit in the precise expression of just the filename [index.php] (which, from my understanding - which could be incorrect - is the only file you want to cache, even if it is using permalinks). Have you tried that?

Right now, you are finding all PHP pages using [".(php)$"].

Comment: Can't do index.php because in this case a PHP MVC framework funnels all requests to index.php. It's called "pretty URLs". So, what we need is a way to move beyond looking at files and looking only at URLs for doing the cache control, and do this from .htaccess if possible.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I overlooked the fact that you wanted to include the passed PHP variables as well.

Comment: I tried the Location directive in .htaccess, but it was failing with a 500 error. I guess I need an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about symlinking the php file to another name in the directory, say `ln -s index.php cachedindex.php`, having apache use cachedindex.php for / and set the cache header on that. Let the framework keep using index.php for all the other pages.

Although since you're working with the developer on this, is there a reason the php code isn't just outputting the appropriate cache header when the right options are set (in this case only when no options are set)?